# Multidimensional (?) dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to save all occurrences of two nouns in a dictionary. If I have the following data:

> "Miss, Universe", "Miss, Marple"; "Miss, Holiday"; "South, Africa"; "Eastern, Time"; "Hello, everybody"; "Miss, Bond".

I'd like to get a dictionary (or something similar) which looks, at the end, like this:

> {{Miss: Universe, Marple, Holiday, Bond}, {South: Africa}, {Eastern: Time}, {Hello: everybody}}.

It don't have to be a dict, but it should be something which is nice to work with, afterwards. (Example: `dict_name["Miss"]` could return "Universe, Marple, Holiday, Bond".

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried? Also, what's wrong with the 2D Dictionary you already posted: `{{Miss: Universe, Marple, Holiday, Bond}, {South: Africa}, {Eastern: Time}, {Hello: everybody}}`?

Comment: What don't you construct a single dimensional dictionary of `{key: list(values)}`?

Comment: What does your program look like so far?  Where is your list of error messages?  What have you done so far in terms of design, research, etc.?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and hints - I could find a solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use defaultdict to do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for x in data:
    k, v = [i.strip() for i in x.split(",")]
    d[k].append(v)
```

Now you can access "Miss" by

```
d['Miss']
```

and it will return a list: `['Universe', 'Marple', 'Holiday']`

Hope it helps

Comment: It helped a lot! Thank you very much! :)